# required a bean of type ...Service that could not be found

Tags: java, spring

Como es que no encuentra el bean del tipo seuService si esta marcado como @service... Tiene algo que ver con la estructura del directorio?

Me salta este error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field seuService in
>   edu.url.uniestbackoffice.controllers.api.TableListsController required
>   a bean of type
>   'edu.url.uniestbackoffice.infraestructura.services.SeuService' that
>   could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> ```
> @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
> ```
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'edu.url.uniestbackoffice.infraestructura.services.SeuService' in your
>   configuration.

---

```
package edu.url.uniestbackoffice.controllers.api;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import edu.url.uniestbackoffice.controllers.api.dto.DataTableResponse;
import edu.url.uniestbackoffice.infraestructura.services.SeuService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/backoffice/api")
public class TableListsController {

@Autowired
SeuService seuService;

@GetMapping("/getseus")
public DataTableResponse getSeus(@RequestBody Object request)
{ DataTableResponse response = new DataTableResponse(); response.setData(seuService.listAllSeus().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())); return response; }

}
```

---

```
package edu.url.uniestbackoffice.infraestructura.services;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import edu.url.uniestbackoffice.entities.Seu;

@Service
public interface SeuService
{ public List<Seu> listAllSeus(); }
```

[image: Estructura de directorios]

Gracias!!

Comment: verifica que la anotación @Service este en la implementación de SeuService.

Answer (score 1):

En la Interface no es necesario anotar el @Service, más bien esta anotación debe de ir en la implementación de dicha interfaz. Verifica que la anotación esté en Impl.
Saludos